# How to get Variable in php when passing through javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am passing my variable through an AJAX request in javascript. How to assign this the value of this variable to a new variable in the tabs.php file?

JS code

```
var build = {
m_count : (document.getElementById('count').value),
}
$.ajax({
    data: build,
    type: "POST",
    url: "tabs.php",});
    success: function(data) {

        console.log(data);
        }
        });
```

Output of console is nothing.

Comment: @Carcigenicate How to use that data. Can you please show me example of using data of $POSTS to assign a value to any variable.

Comment: Please, edit you question, and provide tabs.php for better support.

Comment: `"Output of console is nothing."` - Well, you're not showing us what `tabs.php` does.  If it doesn't respond with anything, then of course there won't be anything written to the console.  As for how to use the value in your PHP code, that would just be `$_POST["m_count"]`.  Any introductory PHP tutorial would show you how to use `$_POST` values.

Comment: Wait, you keep re-asking the same question and then abandoning it after getting useful and helpful responses.  (I'd vote to close this as a duplicate if I hadn't already voted to close it for not including relevant code in the question.)  Are you not bothering to read those responses?  Why are you asking if you're not looking for help?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to assign it. Your value will be accessible on **tabs.php** by the _POST array as it `$_POST['m_count']`.

I also strongly suggest you to test if the array variable **m_count** is set to avoid eventual php error when **m_count** is missing by doing the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['m_count']))
{
    # If possible set the content type header to json app.
    # header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $message = "m_count value is equal to: " . $_POST['m_count'];
    echo json_encode([ "message" => $message ]);
}
```

Also you you have an extra `});` before the success function in your javascript.

```
var build = {
    m_count : document.getElementById('count').value,
}

$.ajax({
    data: build,
    type: "POST",
    url:  "tabs.php",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```

Comment: Am i passing it in right way as i am not able to use it php file

Comment: Or else try to get variables using $_REQUEST['m_count']